# MODX Revo - ajax page reloads in modx

Tags: modx, formit

In Formit, it seems to show the sent forms, the letters are in the mailings, but ajax does not work, the page is reloaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h27JY.png)

Code template:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdFpr.png)

Code chunk form_contacts:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Yb4.png)

Code chunk email_tpl:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqbS.png)

Comment: Do you process `af_complete` or do you have any validation code according to this manual: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/ajaxform Did you try that?

Comment: I don't process it. I haven't tried it.

Comment: I did as in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mwCem31oSw, only ajax works there and the page does not reload.

Comment: How about browser developer console, do you have any error messages there?

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, there are errors, https://pastenow.ru/c53a0915dd25ab66590ff3072241ace2

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, connected jquery, ajax works

Comment: great news! please mark question as solved